# Backrefrence in regular expression(java)

Tags: java, regex

### This regex is used to validate ip address

regex = `"^([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])$"`

> /!\ modified version /!\
>
> regex =  `"^([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.(\\1)\\.(\\1)\\.(\\1)$"`

But the modified version is not working!! why it is not working??

Comment: Define "not working". Also `\\1` expects exact same value as matched by group 1, so in case of regex like `([a-c])\\1` it can match only `aa` `bb` `cc`, not `ac` since group 1 would hold `a` in this case.

Comment: not working == its not vaildating it correclty :D

Comment: In that case what do you mean by "correctly"? :)

Comment: if i give input =  000.12.12.034 , the regex is returning false.. but it should return true.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do, it's not possible with java regex since it has not the feature to reuse sub-patterns. But keep in mind that the assertion *"a shorter pattern is faster"* is totally false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\\1` expects exact same value as matched by group 1, so your regex can find only IPs like

```
123.123.123.123
```

since first element is stored in group 1 and rest of elements needs to match it.

What you seem to be looking for is [limited repetitions `{n}`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit) like

```
String regex = "([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])(\\.([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])){3}";
```

BTW I skipped `^` and `$` flags since `matches(regex)` adds them by default, and if you want to use `matcher.find()` then you probably don't need them since you are probably looking for IP inside some text.

Comment: i tried your regex but its giving me an error `can't find symbol ([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])(\\.([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])){3}`     and the up arrow pointing at  the 25[0-5]

Comment: @syed_sami How exactly are you using this regex? Did you used it as String?

Comment: i'm using it as a string.. just like this 

`String ip = (my input here);
System.out.println(ip.matches(regex));`